# Set DateTimeCreate with EWS Proxy classes

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server

**Is it possible to change CreationDateTime, SentDateTime, etc.????**

I`m tring to create/update message. All run fine, but i need to set field ItemType.CreateDateTime with my values (eg. I need to create message that has time creation not today, but year ego).
I have next code:

```
//Update created item
            ItemIdType itemId = new ItemIdType();
            itemId.Id = savedMessageId;
            itemId.ChangeKey = savedMessageChangeKey;

            ItemType setCreateDT = new ItemType();
            setCreateDT.DateTimeCreated = new System.DateTime(2000, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12);
            setCreateDT.DateTimeCreatedSpecified = true;

            SetItemFieldType setItemField = new SetItemFieldType();
            setItemField.Item = new PathToUnindexedFieldType();
            (setItemField.Item as PathToUnindexedFieldType).FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.itemDateTimeCreated;
            setItemField.Item1 = setCreateDT;

            UpdateItemType request = new UpdateItemType();
            request.ItemChanges = new ItemChangeType[1] { new ItemChangeType() };
            request.ItemChanges[0].Item = itemId;
            request.ItemChanges[0].Updates = new ItemChangeDescriptionType[1];
            request.ItemChanges[0].Updates[0] = setItemField;
            request.MessageDisposition = MessageDispositionType.SaveOnly;
            request.MessageDispositionSpecified = true;

            UpdateItemResponseType updateItemResponse = m_mailbox.UpdateItem(request);
```

That request return Error: "Set action is invalid for property."

If im tring to change Subject, all run OK.

**[UPDATE]**
Found next solution, but it doesn`t work.
There is using extended properties and their ids.

```
PathToExtendedFieldType q = new PathToExtendedFieldType();
        q.PropertyId = 3590; //DeliveryTime
        q.PropertyType = MapiPropertyTypeType.SystemTime;
        q.PropertyIdSpecified = true;
        newItem.ExtendedProperty[0] = new ExtendedPropertyType();
        newItem.ExtendedProperty[0].ExtendedFieldURI = q;
        newItem.ExtendedProperty[0].ExtendedFieldURI.DistinguishedPropertySetIdSpecified = true;
        newItem.ExtendedProperty[0].Item = new System.DateTime(2013, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```

...

```
CreateItemResponseType createItemResponse = m_mailbox.CreateItem(createItemType);
```

It works fine, but i don`t see any changes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second solution is correct, but there are some mistakes.
1) It's better to get access to properties by PropertyTag.
2) You should only set up PropertyTag and PropertyType.

Here is working code:

```
ItemType newItem = xmlParser.LoadItem(); //info for newItem takes from xml
        newItem.ExtendedProperty = new ExtendedPropertyType[1];
        PathToExtendedFieldType q = new PathToExtendedFieldType();
        q.PropertyTag = "3590"; //DeliveryTime
        q.PropertyType = MapiPropertyTypeType.SystemTime;
        newItem.ExtendedProperty[0] = new ExtendedPropertyType();
        newItem.ExtendedProperty[0].ExtendedFieldURI = q;
        newItem.ExtendedProperty[0].Item = new System.DateTime(2014, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
```